# Easier Approach - Jboss AS Upgrade 6.1 to 6.4 - RedHat Linux

Tags: jboss, ansible, redhat, devops, system-administration

We got farm of Red Hat servers which has Jboss 6.1 in our environments. Now we need to upgrade Jboss AS to 6.4. The easy way is to deploy the new version on the server and copy the config files and modules to the new jboss instance. It requires additional space in the filesystem.

Is there any other way to upgrade to 6.4 without having multiple instances. I am looking something like a patch upgrade on the existing Jboss 6.1 instance in CLI mode.

Please update your valuable thoughts.

Cheers,
Jose

Comment: Why is this tagged "Ansible"?

Comment: Do you mean you're on JBoss **EAP** 6.1? JBoss **AS** 6.1 is very different and the answer below would not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use patch in CLI mode, See the guide[1]

[1]https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Installation_Guide/sect-Patching_JBoss_EAP_6.html